# When is it ok to assume /etc/hosts file will be used

Tags: linux, hosts

This may be a bit of an open ended question, and truth be told I would prefer an exhaustive list, however, this has been bugging me for a while: When is it ok for me to assume a program will use the hostnames specified in `/etc/hosts`?

Will any of these programs use it?

- ssh (via `~/.ssh/config`) **YES**
- dhcp (via `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`) **YES**
- iptables **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every program which needs to map between URL and IP address (`gethostbyname` and such) will use `/etc/hosts` and DNS. The order is configurable via `nsswitch.conf`.